# NopCommerce, calling Nop.Web controller methods in Nop.Plugins projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

**Trying to achieve**:
I am writing a restful plugin that would allow searching products from external associated system (website). And allow them to show our products on their website.

Instead of writing everything from scratch, I want to use what is already written in NopCommerce. I have managed to search products, however I am not able to get product images, by using something that already is there.

Inside `CatalogController`, I see `SearchTermAutoComplete` `ActionResult`, it does what I am looking for. But I am not able to call it from my plugin code. I don't want to copy controller files/code into plugin project. Because, then I will have to copy all the extension objects and other dependencies as well.

Is there a way in MVC/NopCommerce by which I access controller code and call them from a plugin?

**Plugin code:**

```
public ActionResult Search(String authToken, string keywords)
        {
            if (!IsAuthTokenValid(authToken, out _tokenStatus))
                return InvalidAuthToken(_tokenStatus);

            var _products = _productService.SearchProducts(0, int.MaxValue, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false, false, false, null, null, 0, keywords, true, true, true);

            if (_products == null || _products.Count <= 0)
                return ErrorOccured("No product was found");
            else
                return Successful(_productHelper.GetProductsJson(_products, _productPictures));
        }
```

P.S. newbie MVC/NopCommerce

**UPDATE**:
I tried to load controller and then call the method, see code below. However, I ended up getting an error in `BaseController's` `RenderPartialViewToString` method.

Code:

```
var _shoppingCartController = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ShoppingCartController>();
            return _shoppingCartController.AddProductToCart_Catalog(productId, 1, quantity);
```

Error upon execution:
    An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
   at Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers.BaseController.RenderPartialViewToString(String viewName, Object model) in d:\NopCommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 67
   at Nop.Web.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.AddProductToCart_Catalog(Int32 productId, Int32 shoppingCartTypeId, Int32 quantity, Boolean forceredirection) in d:\NopCommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web\Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs:line 1547
   at Nop.Plugin.RestService.Controllers.ApiController.AddProductToCart(String authToken, Int32 productId, Int32 quantity)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Comment: You need to use the services to find objects out of your plugin. The controller from namespaces Nop.Web cannot be used directly in you plugin.

Comment: @Dmitry Yeah I understand that, if you see my code above I am using _productService to search products. However there is lot more happening in the actual controllers, like creating some models on fly, calling extension methods, and lots of other stuff. Does it mean I will have to rewrite all this inside my plugin again?

Comment: I have not seen your plugin, and I can not say how it works.
All the necessary services, you can also connect via the controller constructor

Comment: what is it? _if (_products == null || _products.Count <= 0)_ Equal this: _if (!_products.Any())_

Comment: @coder771 this guy and wants

Comment: So, your actual problem is not being able to get the pictures?

Comment: Where is _productPictures defined?  Are you grabbing the pictures using the GetProductPicturesById method from the productService class, located in Nop.Services?

Comment: No really happy guys because of code redundancy, but I managed to get the pictures just like the search auto complete, I had to copy the whole code of 'SearchTermAutoComplete' from catalog controller into my plugin, with some minimum modification. Will post code in some time.